# How to press play button of Audio Controls element using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Using puppeteer I'm trying to press the play button of an audio stream element. The element looks like this:

```
 <audio controls="" autoplay="" preload="auto" id="rearn"><source src="http://51.38.115.114/;stream/1"></audio>.
```

Is there any way to start the stream using puppeteer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
page.$eval('audio', audio => audio.play());
```

Audio is muted in headless mode by default. You can override that with the `--mute-audio` flag which you can configure in the launch options.

Comment: I'm going to try this, it looks promising.

Comment: Is there any way I could check if the audio was playing?

Comment: Don't know, maybe access the player's position?